# Clarification required for the proof of Riemann Lebesgue Lemma

Tags: proof-explanation, riemann-integration

[Riemann Lebesgue Lemma Proof](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_12/rl_lemma.pdf).

In the proof given above, I came across an unfamiliar notation $g= \sum m_i \chi_{[x_i-1,x_i]}$. What does the $\chi$ mean here? Is it the characteristic function of the set $[x_i-1,x_i]$?

Please clarify in detail.

Comment: Yes, it is the characteristic function.

Comment: what role does it play in here?

Comment: It means $g$ is a step function: when $x \in [x_{j-1}, x_j]$, $g(x) = m_j$.

Comment: R-L Lemma is trivial when when the function you start with is the characteristic function of some closed interval. [Verify this!]. Hence it is true for linear combinations of such functions. The basic idea of the proof of R-L Lemma is to approximate the given function by a linear combination of characteristic functions of closed intervals.

Comment: So, when we take the integral from $a$ to $b$, it returns $\sum m_i \delta_i$!?

Comment: Define: $ f(x)= \chi_{[a,b]}$ We want to show that: $\int_a^bf(x)\sin(\lambda x)d x=0$ as $\lambda \to +\infty$. 

$\int_a^bf(x)\sin(\lambda x)dx = \displaystyle {\sum}_{\|P\|\to 0}\chi_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}\sin(\lambda \xi)(x_i-x_{i-1})$ [for any $\xi \in [x_{i-1},x_i]]$ = $ \displaystyle {\sum}_{\|P\|\to 0}\sin(\lambda \xi)(x_i-x_{i-1})=\int_a^b\sin(\lambda x)dx=\frac{1}{\lambda}[\cos(a)-\cos(b)] \leq 2/\lambda<\epsilon, \forall \lambda>\epsilon/2$

@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The appearance of $\lambda $ in the denominator is what makes the whole things work.